# How could I hide API key in my React app and host the working version in GitHub

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

How can I ***hide my Api_key in React***, so that I could safely push it to GitHub and I also want to host it on my **GitHub** so others can use the website!  Help!

Comment: Anyone Help! Hoping anyone in this world sees my question

Comment: Have you tried the github env variables? https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/environment-variables

Comment: Just use secrets https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/encrypted-secrets

Answer (score 3):

Use a `.env` file to store api keys, and use a `.gitignore` file to remove it from github commits.

For example you have a file called `.env` with the following contents

```
KEY={INSERTKEYHERE}
```

Then make a `.gitignore` with the following contents

```
.env
```

The environment variable can be reference in code as

```
{process.env.KEY}
```

Comment: But I also want to host the website in Github! So If there is no Api key in github  How will my website work

Comment: @ADITHYAAJAY in this case, please edit the question to make it more clear, as for now, readers won't know that you want to host it from a Github public repository.

Comment: If you go to the repo's Settings>Secrets you can make a .env file that won't be publicly visible but would be in the process if the code is hosted on github.